# How to create an installation package with all the updates?

Tags: installation, updates, cd-image

How do I create an installable usb image with all the current updates?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I personally would advise using the debian live scripts. They are included in the ubuntu repositories and there is a graphical font end.

```
sudo apt-get install live-magic
```

[image: screen shot]

Full graphical tutorial - http://www.unixmen.com/linux-tutorials/1013-live-magic-create-a-live-cddvd-for-your-installed-ubuntu-debian-based-systems

As you can see, it is a graphical front end for live-build. Building a live CD is not always so easy, and all the graphical tools, including remastersys, sometimes fail. Building a live CD, from scratch, is just not an easy task and requires a fair amount of knowledge and experience. IMO learning the live-build scripts is best as they automate the task, but come with a steep learning curve.

Comment: good comment - probably you should add that into your answer.